# How do meta tags only show on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce, tags

I'm in need of a code snippet to help my meta tag display only on mobile devices, and the default desktop will be hidden.

```
function initScreen() {
    isMobile = (/iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry/).test(navigator.userAgent);
    isTablet = (/iPad/).test(navigator.userAgent);
    if(isMobile) {
        $('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.30, maximum-scale=0.50, minimum-scale=0.25, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">').appendTo('head');
    } else if(isTablet) {
        $('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.95, maximum-scale=0.95, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">').appendTo('head');
    } else {
        $('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.80, maximum-scale=0.80, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">').appendTo('head');
    }
}


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initScreen();
    });
</script>
</head>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You don’t need to hide the viewport meta tag on desktop. Also, the document ready event will fire too late for this method to work.

Comment: ?? Meta tags are not displayed in any device ...

Comment: @evolutionxbox You are right, not very necessary

Comment: @Teemu I plan to show this tag only in mobile version that is not showing on my computer <meta name="theme-color" content="#ff5722">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use `document.write` instead of using jquery append

```
<head>
<script>
    var isMobile = (/iPhone|iPod|Android|BlackBerry/).test(navigator.userAgent);
    isTablet = (/iPad/).test(navigator.userAgent);
    if(isMobile) {
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.30, maximum-scale=0.50, minimum-scale=0.25, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">');
    } else if(isTablet) {
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.95, maximum-scale=0.95, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">');
    } else {
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.80, maximum-scale=0.80, width=device-width, user-scalable=no">');
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank @Tan Duong